# Cálculo em Jquery com máscara e valores grandes

Tags: jquery

Depois de várias etapas, solucionando problemas, estou na parte final de um formulário de pesquisa que estou montando.
Para finalizar, há dois problemas: na columa "Verba mensal", o "toLocaleString" não funciona. O resultado do cálculo de 90,00 x 2 fica 180, ao invés de ficar R$ 180,00 (estranho é que no total funcionou).
Na coluna "Verba diária", se eu colocar a máscara "maskMoney" (que está no Facebook visita site), o cálculo fica "NaN".
O que estaria errado?

Eu editei o código com as correções aqui passadas.
Os campos resolveram o problema, mas os três totais pararam de somar.
Se na linha "Google Adwords" eu colocar R$ 1.250,00 x 2, agora retorna Nan.
Se eu colocar R$ 250,00 x 3, retorna R$ 500,00.

```js
$(".real").maskMoney({
  prefix: 'R$ ',
  thousands: '.',
  decimal: ',',
  affixesStay: true
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var formato = {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'BRL'
  }

  /****** Cálculos Google Adwords ******/
  $('#vd_ga').on('blur', function() {
    var vd_ga = $('#vd_ga').val().replace("R$ ", "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
    var pvm_ga = $('#pvm_ga').val();

    //$('#vm_ga').val(vd_ga * pvm_ga);
    $("#vm_ga").val((vd_ga * pvm_ga).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eam_ga').val(vd_ga * pvm_ga);

  });

  $('#pvm_ga').on('blur', function() {
    var vd_ga = $('#vd_ga').val().replace("R$ ", "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
    var pvm_ga = $('#pvm_ga').val();


    $('#vm_ga').val((vd_ga * pvm_ga).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eam_ga').val(vd_ga * pvm_ga);

  });
  /****** Cálculos Google Adwords ******/

  /****** Cálculos Facebook visita site ******/
  $('#vd_fvs').on('blur', function() {
    //var vd_fvs = $('#vd_fvs').val().replace(',', '.');
    var vd_fvs = $('#vd_fvs').val().replace("R$ ", "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
    var pvm_fvs = $('#pvm_fvs').val();

    $('#vm_fvs').val((vd_fvs * pvm_fvs).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eam_fvs').val(vd_fvs * pvm_fvs);
  });

  $('#pvm_fvs').on('blur', function() {
    //var vd_fvs = $('#vd_fvs').val().replace(',', '.');
    var vd_fvs = $('#vd_fvs').val().replace("R$ ", "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
    var pvm_fvs = $('#pvm_fvs').val();

    $('#vm_fvs').val((vd_fvs * pvm_fvs).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eam_fvs').val(vd_fvs * pvm_fvs);
  });
  /****** Cálculos Facebook visita site ******/

  /****** Cálculos Facebook curtida na página ******/
  $('#vd_fcp').on('blur', function() {
    var vd_fcp = $('#vd_fcp').val().replace("R$ ", "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
    var pvm_fcp = $('#pvm_fcp').val();

    $('#vm_fcp').val((vd_fcp * pvm_fcp).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eam_fcp').val(vd_fcp * pvm_fcp);
  });

  $('#pvm_fcp').on('blur', function() {
    var vd_fcp = $('#vd_fcp').val().replace("R$ ", "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
    var pvm_fcp = $('#pvm_fcp').val();

    $('#vm_fcp').val((vd_fcp * pvm_fcp).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eam_fcp').val(vd_fcp * pvm_fcp);
  });
  /****** Cálculos Facebook curtida na página ******/

  /****** Cálculos Instagram seguidores ******/
  $('#vd_is').on('blur', function() {
    var vd_is = $('#vd_is').val().replace("R$ ", "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
    var pvm_is = $('#pvm_is').val();

    $('#vm_is').val((vd_is * pvm_is).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eam_is').val(vd_is * pvm_is);
  });

  $('#pvm_is').on('blur', function() {
    var vd_is = $('#vd_is').val().replace("R$ ", "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
    var pvm_is = $('#pvm_is').val();

    $('#vm_is').val((vd_is * pvm_is).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eam_is').val(vd_is * pvm_is);
  });
  /****** Cálculos Instagram seguidores ******/

  /****** Cálculo total 1 ******/
  $('#vd_ga, #pvm_ga, #vd_fvs, #pvm_fvs, #vd_fcp, #pvm_fcp, #vd_is, #pvm_is').on('input', function() {
    var vm_ga = parseFloat($("#vm_ga").val().replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));
    var vm_fvs = parseFloat($("#vm_fvs").val().replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));
    var vm_fcp = parseFloat($("#vm_fcp").val().replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));
    var vm_is = parseFloat($("#vm_is").val().replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));

    var total_1 = vm_ga + vm_fvs + vm_fcp + vm_is;

    //if(!isNaN(total_1)) $('#total_1').val(total_1);
    //if(!isNaN(total_1)) $("#total_1").val(total_1.toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    if (!isNaN(total_1)) $('#total_1').val((total_1).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
  });

  /****** Cálculo total 1 ******/

  /*********************************************************************************************/

  /****** Cálculos Facebook impulsionamento de posts ******/
  $('#vd_fip').on('blur', function() {
    var vd_fip = $('#vd_fip').val().replace("R$ ", "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
    var qpm_fip = $('#qpm_fip').val();

    $('#vm_fip').val((vd_fip * qpm_fip).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eap_fip').val(vd_fip * 75);

    var eap_fip = $('#eap_fip').val();

    $('#eatpm_fip').val(qpm_fip * eap_fip);
  });

  $('#qpm_fip').on('blur', function() {
    var vd_fip = $('#vd_fip').val().replace("R$ ", "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
    var qpm_fip = $('#qpm_fip').val();

    $('#vm_fip').val((vd_fip * qpm_fip).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eap_fip').val(vd_fip * 75);

    var eap_fip = $('#eap_fip').val();

    $('#eatpm_fip').val(qpm_fip * eap_fip);
  });
  /****** Cálculos Facebook impulsionamento de posts ******/

  /****** Cálculos Instagram impulsionamento de posts ******/
  $('#vd_iip').on('blur', function() {
    var vd_iip = $('#vd_iip').val().replace("R$ ", "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
    var qpm_iip = $('#qpm_iip').val();

    $('#vm_iip').val((vd_iip * qpm_iip).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eap_iip').val(vd_iip * 75);

    var eap_iip = $('#eap_iip').val();

    $('#eatpm_iip').val(qpm_iip * eap_iip);
  });

  $('#qpm_iip').on('blur', function() {
    var vd_iip = $('#vd_iip').val().replace("R$ ", "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
    var qpm_iip = $('#qpm_iip').val();

    $('#vm_iip').val((vd_iip * qpm_iip).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eap_iip').val(vd_iip * 75);

    var eap_iip = $('#eap_iip').val();

    $('#eatpm_iip').val(qpm_iip * eap_iip);
  });
  /****** Cálculos Instagram impulsionamento de posts ******/

  /****** Cálculo total 2 ******/
  $('#vd_fip, #qpm_fip, #vd_iip, #qpm_iip').on('input', function() {
    var vm_fip = parseFloat($("#vm_fip").val().replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));
    var vm_iip = parseFloat($("#vm_iip").val().replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));

    var total_2 = vm_fip + vm_iip;

    //if(!isNaN(total_2)) $('#total_2').val(total_2);
    //if(!isNaN(total_2)) $("#total_2").val(total_2.toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    if (!isNaN(total_2)) $('#total_2').val((total_2).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
  });
  /****** Cálculo total 2 ******/

  /****** Cálculo totais ******/
  $('#vd_ga, #pvm_ga, #vd_fvs, #pvm_fvs, #vd_fcp, #pvm_fcp, #vd_is, #pvm_is, #vd_fip, #qpm_fip, #vd_iip, #qpm_iip').on('input', function() {
    var total_1 = parseFloat($("#total_1").val().replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));
    var total_2 = parseFloat($("#total_2").val().replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));

    var total_geral = total_1 + total_2;

    //if(!isNaN(total_geral)) $('#total_geral').val(total_geral);
    //if(!isNaN(total_geral)) $("#total_geral").val(total_geral.toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    if (!isNaN(total_geral)) $('#total_geral').val((total_geral).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
  });
  /****** Cálculo totais ******/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.agenciamove.com.br/briefing/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/javascripts/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3 titulo_ferramenta">
    Canais online
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Verba diária
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Período de vericulação mensal
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Verba mensal
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3 titulo_ferramenta">
    Estimativa de alcance mensal
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 canais_titulo">
    Google Adwords
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vd_ga" id="vd_ga" class="real input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="pvm_ga" id="pvm_ga" class="input_geral_2" type="text" /><span class="canais_titulo"> dias</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vm_ga" id="vm_ga" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3">
    <input name="eam_ga" id="eam_ga" class="input_geral_2" type="text" readonly /><span class="canais_titulo"> Cliques</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3 canais_titulo">
    Facebook visita site
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vd_fvs" id="vd_fvs" class="real input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="pvm_fvs" id="pvm_fvs" class="input_geral_2" type="text" /><span class="canais_titulo"> dias</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vm_fvs" id="vm_fvs" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3">
    <input name="eam_fvs" id="eam_fvs" class="input_geral_2" type="text" readonly /><span class="canais_titulo"> Cliques</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3 canais_titulo">
    Facebook curtida na página
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vd_fcp" id="vd_fcp" class="real input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="pvm_fcp" id="pvm_fcp" class="input_geral_2" type="text" /><span class="canais_titulo"> dias</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vm_fcp" id="vm_fcp" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3">
    <input name="eam_fcp" id="eam_fcp" class="input_geral_2" type="text" readonly /><span class="canais_titulo"> Cliques</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3 canais_titulo">
    Instagram seguidores
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vd_is" id="vd_is" class="real input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="pvm_is" id="pvm_is" class="input_geral_2" type="text" /><span class="canais_titulo"> dias</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vm_is" id="vm_is" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3">
    <input name="eam_is" id="eam_is" class="input_geral_2" type="text" readonly /><span class="canais_titulo"> Cliques</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3"></div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 canais_titulo text-right">
    Valor total verba mês
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="total_1" id="total_1" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3"></div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="titulo_pag_ferramenta">Já na ferramenta de impulsionamentos, basta colocar o valor diário e a quantidade de posts que deseja estar postando mensalmente:</div>

<hr />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Canais online
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Verba diária
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Quantidade de posts mês
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Verba mensal
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Estimativa de alcance por post
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Estimativa de alcance total de posts mês
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 canais_titulo">
    Facebook impulsionamento de posts
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vd_fip" id="vd_fip" class="real input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="qpm_fip" id="qpm_fip" class="input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vm_fip" id="vm_fip" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="eap_fip" id="eap_fip" class="input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="eatpm_fip" id="eatpm_fip" class="input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 canais_titulo">
    Instagram impulsionamento de posts
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vd_iip" id="vd_iip" class="real input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="qpm_iip" id="qpm_iip" class="input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vm_iip" id="vm_iip" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="eap_iip" id="eap_iip" class="input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="eatpm_iip" id="eatpm_iip" class="input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 canais_titulo text-right">
    Valor total verba mês
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="total_2" id="total_2" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">

  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">

  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 canais_titulo text-right">
    Geral
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="total_geral" id="total_geral" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "na columa "Verba mensal", o "toLocaleString" não funciona. O resultado
>   do cálculo de 90,00 x 2 fica 180, ao invés de ficar R$ 180,00"...

Coloque a multiplicação entre parênteses e o `toLocaleString` fora:

```
$("#vm_ga").val((vd_ga * pvm_ga).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
```

> "Na coluna "Verba diária", se eu colocar a máscara "maskMoney" (que
>   está no Facebook visita site), o cálculo fica "NaN"."

Precisa tirar o símbolo `R$` com um replace senão ele é `isNaN`:

```
var vd_fvs = $('#vd_fvs').val().replace("R$ ","").replace('.','').replace(',', '.');
```

**Exemplo com código otimizado:**

```js
$(".real").maskMoney({
  prefix: 'R$ ',
  thousands: '.',
  decimal: ',',
  affixesStay: true
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   
   function rePlace(i){
      return parseFloat(i.replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));
   }
   
  var formato = {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'BRL'
  }

  /****** Cálculos Google Adwords ******/
  $('#vd_ga, #pvm_ga').on('input', function() {
    var vd_ga = rePlace($('#vd_ga').val());
    var pvm_ga = $('#pvm_ga').val();

    $("#vm_ga").val((vd_ga * pvm_ga).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eam_ga').val(vd_ga * pvm_ga);

  });
  /****** Cálculos Google Adwords ******/

  /****** Cálculos Facebook visita site ******/
  $('#vd_fvs, #pvm_fvs').on('input', function() {
    var vd_fvs = rePlace($('#vd_fvs').val());
    var pvm_fvs = $('#pvm_fvs').val();

    $('#vm_fvs').val((vd_fvs * pvm_fvs).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eam_fvs').val(vd_fvs * pvm_fvs);
  });
  /****** Cálculos Facebook visita site ******/

  /****** Cálculos Facebook curtida na página ******/
  $('#vd_fcp, #pvm_fcp').on('input', function() {
    var vd_fcp = rePlace($('#vd_fcp').val());
    var pvm_fcp = $('#pvm_fcp').val();

    $('#vm_fcp').val((vd_fcp * pvm_fcp).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eam_fcp').val(vd_fcp * pvm_fcp);
  });
  /****** Cálculos Facebook curtida na página ******/

  /****** Cálculos Instagram seguidores ******/
  $('#vd_is, #pvm_is').on('input', function() {
    var vd_is = rePlace($('#vd_is').val());
    var pvm_is = $('#pvm_is').val();

    $('#vm_is').val((vd_is * pvm_is).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eam_is').val(vd_is * pvm_is);
  });
  /****** Cálculos Instagram seguidores ******/

  /****** Cálculo total 1 ******/
  $('#vd_ga, #pvm_ga, #vd_fvs, #pvm_fvs, #vd_fcp, #pvm_fcp, #vd_is, #pvm_is').on('input', function() {
    var vm_ga = rePlace($("#vm_ga").val()) || 0;
    var vm_fvs = rePlace($("#vm_fvs").val()) || 0;
    var vm_fcp = rePlace($("#vm_fcp").val()) || 0;
    var vm_is = rePlace($("#vm_is").val()) || 0;

    var total_1 = vm_ga + vm_fvs + vm_fcp + vm_is;
    
    if (!isNaN(total_1)) $('#total_1').val((total_1).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
  });

  /****** Cálculo total 1 ******/

  /*********************************************************************************************/

  /****** Cálculos Facebook impulsionamento de posts ******/
  $('#vd_fip, #qpm_fip').on('input', function() {
    var vd_fip = rePlace($('#vd_fip').val());
    var qpm_fip = $('#qpm_fip').val();

    $('#vm_fip').val((vd_fip * qpm_fip).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eap_fip').val(vd_fip * 75);

    var eap_fip = $('#eap_fip').val();

    $('#eatpm_fip').val(qpm_fip * eap_fip);
  });
  /****** Cálculos Facebook impulsionamento de posts ******/

  /****** Cálculos Instagram impulsionamento de posts ******/
  $('#vd_iip, #qpm_iip').on('input', function() {
    var vd_iip = rePlace($('#vd_iip').val());
    var qpm_iip = $('#qpm_iip').val();

    $('#vm_iip').val((vd_iip * qpm_iip).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
    $('#eap_iip').val(vd_iip * 75);

    var eap_iip = $('#eap_iip').val();

    $('#eatpm_iip').val(qpm_iip * eap_iip);
  });
  /****** Cálculos Instagram impulsionamento de posts ******/

  /****** Cálculo total 2 ******/
  $('#vd_fip, #qpm_fip, #vd_iip, #qpm_iip').on('input', function() {
    var vm_fip = rePlace($("#vm_fip").val()) || 0;
    var vm_iip = rePlace($("#vm_iip").val()) || 0;

    var total_2 = vm_fip + vm_iip;

    if (!isNaN(total_2)) $('#total_2').val((total_2).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
  });
  /****** Cálculo total 2 ******/

  /****** Cálculo totais ******/
  $('#vd_ga, #pvm_ga, #vd_fvs, #pvm_fvs, #vd_fcp, #pvm_fcp, #vd_is, #pvm_is, #vd_fip, #qpm_fip, #vd_iip, #qpm_iip').on('input', function() {
    var total_1 = rePlace($("#total_1").val()) || 0;
    var total_2 = rePlace($("#total_2").val()) || 0;

    var total_geral = total_1 + total_2;

    if (!isNaN(total_geral)) $('#total_geral').val((total_geral).toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
  });
  /****** Cálculo totais ******/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/javascripts/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3 titulo_ferramenta">
    Canais online
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Verba diária
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Período de vericulação mensal
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Verba mensal
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3 titulo_ferramenta">
    Estimativa de alcance mensal
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 canais_titulo">
    Google Adwords
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vd_ga" id="vd_ga" class="real input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="pvm_ga" id="pvm_ga" class="input_geral_2" type="text" /><span class="canais_titulo"> dias</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vm_ga" id="vm_ga" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3">
    <input name="eam_ga" id="eam_ga" class="input_geral_2" type="text" readonly /><span class="canais_titulo"> Cliques</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3 canais_titulo">
    Facebook visita site
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vd_fvs" id="vd_fvs" class="real input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="pvm_fvs" id="pvm_fvs" class="input_geral_2" type="text" /><span class="canais_titulo"> dias</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vm_fvs" id="vm_fvs" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3">
    <input name="eam_fvs" id="eam_fvs" class="input_geral_2" type="text" readonly /><span class="canais_titulo"> Cliques</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3 canais_titulo">
    Facebook curtida na página
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vd_fcp" id="vd_fcp" class="real input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="pvm_fcp" id="pvm_fcp" class="input_geral_2" type="text" /><span class="canais_titulo"> dias</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vm_fcp" id="vm_fcp" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3">
    <input name="eam_fcp" id="eam_fcp" class="input_geral_2" type="text" readonly /><span class="canais_titulo"> Cliques</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3 canais_titulo">
    Instagram seguidores
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vd_is" id="vd_is" class="real input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="pvm_is" id="pvm_is" class="input_geral_2" type="text" /><span class="canais_titulo"> dias</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vm_is" id="vm_is" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3">
    <input name="eam_is" id="eam_is" class="input_geral_2" type="text" readonly /><span class="canais_titulo"> Cliques</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3"></div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 canais_titulo text-right">
    Valor total verba mês
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="total_1" id="total_1" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3"></div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="titulo_pag_ferramenta">Já na ferramenta de impulsionamentos, basta colocar o valor diário e a quantidade de posts que deseja estar postando mensalmente:</div>

<hr />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Canais online
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Verba diária
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Quantidade de posts mês
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Verba mensal
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Estimativa de alcance por post
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 titulo_ferramenta">
    Estimativa de alcance total de posts mês
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 canais_titulo">
    Facebook impulsionamento de posts
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vd_fip" id="vd_fip" class="real input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="qpm_fip" id="qpm_fip" class="input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vm_fip" id="vm_fip" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="eap_fip" id="eap_fip" class="input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="eatpm_fip" id="eatpm_fip" class="input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 canais_titulo">
    Instagram impulsionamento de posts
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vd_iip" id="vd_iip" class="real input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="qpm_iip" id="qpm_iip" class="input_geral" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="vm_iip" id="vm_iip" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="eap_iip" id="eap_iip" class="input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="eatpm_iip" id="eatpm_iip" class="input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 canais_titulo text-right">
    Valor total verba mês
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="total_2" id="total_2" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">

  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">

  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 canais_titulo text-right">
    Geral
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <input name="total_geral" id="total_geral" class="real input_geral" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Quase deu certo. Eu editei o código com as correções aqui passadas. Acima explico o que houve.

Comment: Os campos resolveram o problema, mas os três totais pararam de somar. Se na linha "Google Adwords" eu colocar R$ 1.250,00 x 2, agora retorna NaN. Se eu colocar R$ 250,00 x 3, retorna R$ 500,00.

Comment: Funcionou!! Só os três totais agora, que, mesmo colocado o replace pararam de funcionar.

Comment: Eu coloquei a última atualização que fiz aqui. Devo estar incomodando, mas será minha última tentativa. A soma dos blocos, faz somente se preencher duas linhas. O total geral, mesmo depois de colocado o replace não funciona.

Comment: Incomoda nada. Estamos aqui pra ajudar. Vou dar uma olhada no codigo.

Comment: Mas eu substituo o vm_ga + vm_fvs + vm_fcp + vm_is ?

Comment: Eu me expressei mal. Você disse para trocar a linha var total_1. A linha var total_1 atual é essa var total_1 = vm_ga + vm_fvs + vm_fcp + vm_is; Se eu colocar var total_1 = parseFloat($("#total_1").val().replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").replace('.', '').replace(',', '.')); fica sem somar.

Comment: Agora sim! Deu certo! Juro que é a última pergunta: Porque para fazer todos os totais, todos os campos tem que estar preenchidos? Por exemplo, se eu preencher uma  ou duas linhas, não é possível fazer o cálculo? Mas agradeço desde já pelo aprendizado. PS: Eu atualizei o código aqui.

Comment: @RogérioPancini Coloquei na minha resposta o código todo otimizado e funcionando como vc queria.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução muito simples seria você utilizar:

```
var resultado = 99.00 * 2;
$('#nomedavariavel').val(resultado.toFixed(2));
$('#nomedavariavel').unmask().mask('#.##0,00', { reverse: true });
```

Abraços.